# How to pop-up select menu using customized css styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display select dropdown as a pop-up menu using css. I am trying to display select menu like in this link.

I tried some styling but it is displaying as normal dropdown.

Is there anyway to display select menu as pop-up [dropdown](https://app.lendingkart.com/lkart/check_eligibility_direct.html#!/home?from=applyNow)

```css
/* Scrollbar styles */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 12px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: darkgrey;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  /*background: #7bac10;*/
}


/****  floating-Lable css  ****/

.floating-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.floating-input,
.floating-select {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}

.floating-input:focus,
.floating-select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #5264AE;
}

label {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.floating-input:focus~label,
.floating-input:not(:placeholder-shown)~label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264AE;
}

.floating-select:focus~label,
.floating-select:not([value=""]):valid~label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264AE;
}


/* active state */

.floating-input:focus~.bar:before,
.floating-input:focus~.bar:after,
.floating-select:focus~.bar:before,
.floating-select:focus~.bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.floating-textarea {
  height: 90px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}


/* highlighter */

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* active state */

.floating-input:focus~.highlight,
.floating-select:focus~.highlight {
  -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}


/* animation */

@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-label">
  <input class="floating-input" type="password" placeholder=" ">
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <label>Name</label>
</div>
<div class="floating-label">
  <select class="floating-select" onclick="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Alabama</option>
            <option value="2">Boston</option>
            <option value="3">Ohaio</option>
            <option value="4">New York</option>
            <option value="5">Washington</option>
          </select>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <label>Select</label>
</div>

<div class="floating-label">
  <textarea class="floating-input floating-textarea" placeholder=" "></textarea>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <label>Textarea</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know about pop-up dropdown but can a `modal` might be a solution for you? You may then insert a dropdown menu there.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is using a href and the `:target` option. That's a clever trick for pure css popups (see [here](https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO)). However that means that you'll have to put the list inside the link, which then leads to several css issues. Here is my try, definatelly needs some style fixing...

```js
$('#target2').on('change', function() {
  $('#target1').val(this.value);
})
```

```css
/* Scrollbar styles */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 12px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: darkgrey;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  /*background: #7bac10;*/
}


/****  floating-Lable css  ****/

.floating-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.floating-input,
.floating-select {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}

.floating-input:focus,
.floating-select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #5264AE;
}

label {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.floating-input:focus~label,
.floating-input:not(:placeholder-shown)~label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264AE;
}

.floating-select:focus~label,
.floating-select:not([value=""]):valid~label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264AE;
}


/* active state */

.floating-input:focus~.bar:before,
.floating-input:focus~.bar:after,
.floating-select:focus~.bar:before,
.floating-select:focus~.bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.floating-textarea {
  height: 90px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}


/* highlighter */

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* active state */

.floating-input:focus~.highlight,
.floating-select:focus~.highlight {
  -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}


/* animation */

@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="floating-label">
  <input class="floating-input" type="password" placeholder=" ">
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <label>Name</label>
</div>
<div class="floating-label">
  <a class="button floating-select" href="#popup1">
    <select class="floating-select" id="target1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Alabama</option>
            <option value="2">Boston</option>
            <option value="3">Ohaio</option>
            <option value="4">New York</option>
            <option value="5">Washington</option></select></a>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <label>Select</label>
</div>

<div class="floating-label">
  <textarea class="floating-input floating-textarea" placeholder=" "></textarea>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <label>Textarea</label>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Select state</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   Choose one of the above:
        <select id="target2" class="floating-select" onclick="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Alabama</option>
            <option value="2">Boston</option>
            <option value="3">Ohaio</option>
            <option value="4">New York</option>
            <option value="5">Washington</option>
          </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```